# When the second hand bisects the angle between the hour hand and the minute hand

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

Find the exact time between $2.25$ pm and $2.26$ pm when the second hand bisects the angle between the hour hand and the minute hand.

I mention below my solution to this question. I would like to know whether my solution is correct and also are there any other ways to solve this question.

As the second hand bisects the angle formed by the hour and minute hand:
angle between hour and second hand $=$ angle between second and minute hand.

Let $x$ be the number of seconds from $2.25$ to $2.26$ when angle between hour and minute hand is bisected.

Hour hand rotates through $\frac{1}{120}$ degrees per minute.
As angle between hour and second hand $=$ angle between second and minute hand.

After $x$ seconds hour hand from the beginning of the hour will rotate through-
$60$ degrees $+$ $\frac{x}{120}$ degrees.

After $x$ seconds minute hand from the beginning of the hour will rotate through-
$150$ degrees + $\frac{x}{10}$ degrees.

As angle between hour and second hand = angle between second and minute hand:
$6x$ degrees $-$ $(60 + \frac{x}{120})$ degrees $=$ $150$ degrees $+$ $\frac{x}{10}$ degrees $-$ $6x$ degrees

....Simplifying we get:
$x= \frac{25200}{1427} \approx 17.659$ seconds.

Comment: This looks fine to me. The only error is when you say $\frac{25200}{1427} = 17.659$, which is manifestly false.

Comment: @TonyK sorry but I did not get what you said.

Comment: TonyK is pointing out that it is not an equality because $\frac {25200}{1427}$ is not a terminating decimal.  Your last = should be $\approx$

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You are right except for the the conversion to decimal, which is not exact.  Artin has fixed that by changing the $=$ to $\approx$.  It depends on the department-math insists that $=$ is exact equality, while others accept it as "reasonably close".

Comment: The OP's calculation is incorrect. A new user has provided an answer with the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, after $x$ seconds from 2:25, the second hand bisects the angle between the hour and the minute hand. Then, measured in degrees, the angle made by the hour hand at $2:25:x$ time, namely at 2 hours 25 minutes and $x$ seconds, will be

$$= 2 \cdot 30+25 \cdot 1/2+s \cdot 1/120,$$ because the hour hand moves 30 degrees in 1 hour, half a degree in 1 minute, and 1/120 degree in 1 second.

Similarly, the angle made by the minute hand at $2:25:x$ time will be $$= 25 \cdot 6+s \cdot 1/10,$$
because the minute hand moves 6 degrees in 1 minute and 1/10 degree in 1 second.

The angle moved by the second hand in $s$ seconds is $s\cdot 6$ degrees.

Now the bisection condition means that the angle made by the second hand minus the angle made by the hour hand equals the angle made by the minute hand minus the angle made by the second hand. Therefore,

\begin{align}
&6s - (2 \cdot 30+25 \cdot 1/2+s \cdot 1/120)= 25 \cdot 6+s \cdot 1/10 -6s\\
&\implies 12s-s/10-s /120=150+60+25/2\\
&\implies 1427s/120 = 222.5\\
&\implies s = (222.5 \cdot 120)/1427\\
&\implies s \approx 18.71.\\
\end{align}

That is, the bisection occurs after approximately $18.71$ seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your result is correct, but your post is a bit difficult to read. Please see this [MathJax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for details on how to format mathematical expressions.